# How to modify one’s input in a bash interactive script?

Tags: bash, input, scripting

I have written a small bash script to fill a sqlite database :

```
#!/bin/sh

echo « What Number ?"
read Nb
echo « What tags ?"
read Tag
echo « What item ? »
read Item

sqlite3 mydatabase.db "insert into Data (Number,Tag,Item) values ($Number,\ »$Tag\",\"$Item\ ");"
```

I start answering

```
1017
0DN
This item is for sale
```

Then I realize I should have written "This item is NOT for sale"

If I try to move back with the back arrows, I get this sign : ^[[D, again and again…

I can of course delete "for sale" and write it all over again. In that case it is easy. But I sometimes write a longer description, and this would be a  chore…

How can I insert a modification in the answer other than by deleting text ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Benjamin W. Definitely… Thank you very much. Should I delete the question ?

Comment: It can serve as a pointer to the other question and help people find it; I wouldn't necessarily delete it, unless you think they're really exactly the same.

Comment: @Benjamin W. OK. Thanks again.